# Issue adding space from /home to /var with ext4 fs debian 11

Tags: partition, disk-space-utilization, home-directory, var

My /var is full on 9.1GB and I need to increase space to 100GB from /home that has 1.4TB. When I run fdisk it keeps giving me the same default amount of space (9.1GB). Is the another way of adding more space from /home to /var that I can use to resolve this issue.
These are physical partitions (take space from /dev/sda1 add to /dev/sda3)
Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you using LVM?

Comment: Pardon the delayed response due to loadshedding, No it's physical partitions, /dev/sda3

Comment: What file system type for each of these volumes? Some cannot be reduced. Please also edit to add which operating system.  And show each block device, size, and mount point.